# Scaling data (MinMaxScaler and StandardScaler) before passing it into recurrent neural network and its effect on the output

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I have a time series with values in range <0, 1000> and I made three experiments.

- in the first one I was passing original values into RNN
- in the second one I use MinMaxScaler() with default range of 0-1
- in the third one i used StandardScaler()

I noticed strange anomaly when RNN was to predict series of zeros in my time series. With original data it did it correctly and i expected similar behavior during another experiments but instead,predictions were much worse. 
Below images representing results of three experiments (red - predicted, black - real):

[unchanged dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLdgY.png)

[MinMaxScaler() used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pT0f.png)

[StandardScaler() used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYmkS.png)

We can observe huge difference in zero values. I expected similar results not matter if I use scaling or not. Why is it so? Could anyone explain how method of scalling can affect neural network performance? I want to add second channel (with binary values) and I need to scale it somehow. How to deal with it?

Comment: Take a look at this post https://medium.com/greyatom/why-how-and-when-to-scale-your-features-4b30ab09db5e

Comment: Thanks, but I know why we use scaling. My question is why output (especially zeros) has changed as you can see in given pics.

Comment: It is also mentioned there. The effect of scaling depends on the algorithm or model being used. Maybe the intial weight initalization or the training algorithm is such a way that the 0 have changed in that manner

Comment: So I should play around with weights initialization. Do you have another idea what ought I do?